# How to set different Kafka message keys in different threads using Thread Context Map Lookup

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j2

I am using Kafka appender in log4j. I want to have different message keys in different threads (according to request-id...).

I've set thread context in java code, for example:

ThreadContext.put("key",zmqBrokerAddress);

and I change my config file according to the documentation.

```
    <Kafka name="Kafka" topic="${env:kafka.topic.infrastructure}" key = "${ctx:key}">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %message ${ctx:key}"/>
        <Property name="bootstrap.servers">${env:kafka.server}</Property>
    </Kafka>
```

...

When I read a message in the  consumer, I get the key as a part of the message (something expected) but the value of the key field is "${ctx:key}"

[consumer log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMic4.png)

Comment: Try using `$${ctx:key}` in value of `pattern` attribute of `<PatternLayout>` element

Comment: @VikasSachdeva thank you. But I already have done this. And I have context key value as a part of the message, I want it in a Kafka field key. I added a screenshot of the consumer log.